# Using Range() with array formulas in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a VBA formula, let's say

```
Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaArray = "=MATCH(RC[-1],Sheet1!C1,0)"
```

When I run the macro it enters this into each cell

```
=MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0)
```

I want the `RC[-1]` argument to return cell A2, A3, A4, etc. It's currently returning A2 for all rows. How do I do this?

I also tried `ActiveCell.FormulaArray` and a for loop but it's far too slow for the number of rows I have.

Comment: If you want it to be entered as an array, which this simple Match is not, you will need to enter it into B2 first and then fill down to the bottom.  `.FormulaArray` will treat it as if you highlighted the entire range and put the formula in the first cell then hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter which enters the same formula in all the cells.

Comment: @ScottCraner Is there a way to Ctrl-Shift-Enter all cells individually through VBA that does not involve looping through all cells? I tried a for loop but it's very slow, even slower than doing it manually.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in all the comments:

You will need to enter it into B2 first and then fill down to the bottom.

`.FormulaArray` will treat it as if you highlighted the entire range and put the formula in the first cell then hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter which enters the same formula in all the cells.

```
Range("B2").FormulaArray = "=MATCH(RC[-1],Sheet1!C1,0)"
Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
```

Comment: It takes a very long time to run. It's something I'll have to deal with separately and optimize, but it works. Thank you.

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjj you may want to look into loading the data into memory array and do the calculations that your array formula is doing and store the output into another array then post it all at once.  Array formulas are very consuming and depending on the number and reference data may even crash excel.  I only use Array formula for few answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `FormulaArray` to `FormulaR1C1`

```
Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=MATCH(RC[-1],Sheet1!C1,0)"
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work because it's an array formula. How do I combine R1C1 and array notation?

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjj that simple match is not an array formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner It's not, but the real formula is. It's very long and not necessary to the question (beyond knowing it's an array formula) so I edited it for simplicity.

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjj how long? FormulaArray has a 255 character limit.  Also see my comment above for your answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner It's around 200 characters.